# Overloaded operator << outputs bool value. why?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, operator-overloading, most-vexing-parse

xml_attribute.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef XML_ATTRIBUTET_H
#define XML_ATTRIBUTET_H

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct XML_AttributeT{

    std::string tag;
    std::string value;

    //constructors
    explicit XML_AttributeT(std::string const& tag, std::string const& value);
    explicit XML_AttributeT(void);

    //overloaded extraction operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, XML_AttributeT const& attribute);
};
#endif
```

xml_attribute.cpp

```
#include "xml_attribute.h"

//Constructors
XML_AttributeT::XML_AttributeT(std::string const& tag_, std::string const& value_)
: tag{tag_}
, value{value_}
{}
XML_AttributeT::XML_AttributeT(void){}

//overloaded extraction operator
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, XML_AttributeT const attribute){
    return out << attribute.tag << "=" << attribute.value;
}
```

driver.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "xml_attribute.h"

int main(){
    using namespace std;

    XML_AttributeT a();
    cout << a << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output from the driver is a '1' but I want it to be an '=' sign.
Why is it outputting the reference to a?
If I change `XML_AttributeT a();` to `XML_AttributeT a;` it doesn't even compile.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Ah, the most vexing parse. Since you're using C++11, you have the option of uniform initialization with `{}` instead of `()`.

Comment: The second argument of your `operator<<` is declared as `XML_AttributeT const` (i.e. pass by value), but the friend declaration uses `XML_AttributeT const &` (pass by reference). They must be identical (I'd recommend pass by reference).

Comment: @jogojapan ugh, nice eye. fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chris is correct. Your initial issue is that `XML_AttributeT a()` is interpreted as a function declaration. `clang++` will actually warn you of this:

```
Untitled.cpp:33:21: warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]
    XML_AttributeT a();
```

You can use `a{}` instead to fix this.

At this point you get a new error:

```
Untitled.cpp:34:10: error: use of overloaded operator '<<' is ambiguous (with operand types 'ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'XML_AttributeT')
    cout << a << endl;
```

This is because of what jogojapan said. Your implemented `operator<<` is using `XML_AttributeT const` as the attribute type instead of `XML_AttributeT const &`. If you fix that, then it compiles and gives you the result you want.

Comment: FWIW, upon trying to output that with GCC (-Waddress), you get a warning of *the address of XML_AttributeT a() will always evaluate as true*, which is a step in the right direction, albeit not a very big one.